# Этимология слова «дудки»

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Почему восклицание, выражающее отрицание, несогласие, отказ от чего-л. (МАС), обозначается словом «дудки»? Как давно оно употребляется в таком значении?

Comment: Этимологию не надо ли закавычить, Aer? Предлагаю вообще  заменить на «Происхождение понятия...».

Comment: @shampar а зачем кавычить?

Comment: Вопрос Ваш — о значении слова в переносном смысле, в жаргонном, в составе фразеологизма, и эта-то его история Вам и интересна. Ваша же шапка вопроса (стандартная что ли) и метка на его суть не указывают.

Answer (score 2):

Точно это вроде бы неизвестно. Самая правдоподобная версия, по-моему - происхождение от слова "дудеть", которое раньше в переносном смысле означало "врать", то есть "дудки" = "враки". Постепенно смысл выражения трансформировался из "врёшь ты всё!" в простое отрицание "ну уж нет!"

Comment: "Дудеть" — надоедать нудными разговорами и т.п., это зафиксировано в словарях. (Ср. "Не дуди!".) Про "дудки" действительно никакой информации найти не получается; околонародная этимология охватывает весь спектр, от бирюлек до волынок, но каких-то особо убедительных версий не приводит.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свою версию.
*Мои предки по материнской линии после отмены крепостного права переселились в деревню, где я затем и родился :), достаточно большим количеством семей из Воронежской губернии. Характерный говор и множество диалектных слов сделали моё детство весьма интересным :)*
Так вот, мой дед утверждал, что фраза `"Нет уж, дудки!"` должна писаться в виде `"Нет уж, дутки!"`, т.е. враки, лжа, поскольку у слова дуть в словаре моих предков было и значение `"врать, сочинять"`, а слово `"дутый"` могло значить `"придуманный, лживый"`.

Answer (score -1):

Больше всего мне понравилось достаточно развёрнутое определение на [Ответах](https://otvet.mail.ru/answer/282246646)

> **Цитата из проекта ["Ответы":](https://otvet.mail.ru/answer/282246646)**
>   *Впервые встречается у «отца истории», древнегреческого историка Геродота (V в. до н. э,), который в первой книге своей «Истории» приводит следующий эпизод из биографии персидского царя Кира.*
>
> Когда Кир покорял греков-мидян, то малоазийские греки, которых он раньше безуспешно склонял к союзу с Персией, поспешили заявить о своем согласии. Тогда персидский царь рассказал их посланцам басню, которую приписывают древнегреческому баснописцу Эзопу (VI в. до н. э.) : «Один флейтист, увидевши рыб в море, стал играть на флейте, ожидая, что они выйдут к нему на сушу. Обманувшись в надежде, он взял сеть, закинул ее и вытащил множество рыб. Видя, как рыбы бьются в сетях, он сказал им: «Перестаньте плясать; когда я играл на флейте, вы не хотели выходить и плясать» .

От себя могу лишь добавить, что *"дух, дуть, душа, дышать, вдох/выдох"* для меня до сей поры могут являться синонимами друг друга (покуда мне не докажут обратное) и восприниматься как нечто призрачно-нереальное, воздушно-пустотное, материально-обесцененное.
Духовые инструменты, ([а значит и дуда](https://www.chitalnya.ru/work/2274630/)), материальных ценностей не производят, а потому ответное предложение "дуды" в обмен на ваш "никчёмный" товар также вполне очевидно.

Comment: Ваше P.S. «От себя» какое отношение к вопросу имеет или к цитате?

Comment: Моё "От себя" было сформулировано на этой странице и благодаря заданному здесь же вопросу, а потому является "дочерним элементом" оного. Ведь "дудки", как отрицание чужого "душевно-духовного", а чаще "душевно-бездуховного", то-есть, пустого взамен на произведённые мной некие вполне даже материальные блага - это не есть "гут", это есть блеф и обман. Вот потому и "дудки"...

Answer (score -1):

Это - возражение, не согласие с чем-то. "Нет уж, дудки" , "вот вам дудки", "дудки вам, а не..."
В одной старой книге встретилось выражение "дудки вам маковые". В маке имеет ценность только поспевшая головка. После срезания маковок остаются никому не нужные дудки - пустотелые стебли от мака.
Поэтому "дудки" означает - пустышка, ничего не стояшая вещь, ерунда, ничего, ноль.