# О переносном значении глагола «дудеть»

Tags: этимология, лексика, фразеология, значение-слов

1. Из словаря: http://nskhuman.ru/unislov/slovar.php?nslovo=22718

**ДУДЕТЬ**, однообразно и надоедливо говорить о чем-либо; повторять, твердить одно и то же, разговорное, переносное значение .

2. Но существует мнение, что ***дудеть*** в переносном значении – это врать, обманывать, а не твердить одно и то же.
3. С этим значением связывают известное  выражение у Даля в статье «дуда» [https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Страница:Толковый_словарь._Том_1_(Даль_1903).djvu/639](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C._%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC_1_(%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C_1903).djvu/639) ***Полно, братъ, ду́дки! не обманешь.***
4. Так что означает слово «дудки»  в этом предложении у Даля?  Дудка – это название действия: дудеть – дудка, хватит (чего?) дудки?

И чего же все-таки хватит: **твердить одно и то же или обманывать?**

Похожий вопрос на эту тему [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435814/Этимология-слова-дудки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435814/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Междометие «дудки» есть у Розенталя, он приводит пример из «Конька-Горбунка»: «Что, опять на окиян? – Говорит царю Иван. – **Нет уж, дудки, ваша милость!** Уж и то во мне всё сбилось. **Не поеду ни за что!»**

Видно, что в данном случае это категорический отказ.

Я читала материалы на эту тему и раньше склонялась к мысли, что «дудки» – **это действительно  «враки»,** а дудеть – это врать. Тогда у Даля получается: «Полно, брат,  врать, не обманешь».

Но потом стала сомневаться. **В словарях такого переносного значения нет**, в том числе у Даля, *дудеть* – это скорее твердить одно и то же. Тогда фразу можно прочитать так:  **Хватит твердить одно и то же**, твои доводы меня не убеждают – **не заманишь (вместо «не обманешь»)**.

Сначала  это звучало так:  ***нет, хватит дудки*** (дудения, дудеть), а потом ее сократили: ***нет, дудки!*** И тогда исходный смысл выражения теряется, а этимология стновится неясной.

Поэтому мне интересно, какое переносное значение у слова ***дудеть*** – **врать или твердить одно и то же?** Ведь и в современном значении «дудки» – это  же отказ, а не обвинение во лжи.

**Какую из версий можно доказать?**

Answer (score 1):

Слово дудки в значении "вранье","ложь" мне известно. Этимология хорошо понятна.

Но мне известно (из самого раннего детства) и значение близкое к современному "фиг вам", "обломится" и т.п. К сожалению, не могу найти подтверждения в словарях, но такое значение очень бы хорошо объясняло и далевсвкую "пословицу", и вообще некоторые случаи использования, не подпадающие явно под другие значения.

Вот с одного сайта: "Нет уж, дудки" "Ну уж дудки" " А вот дудки тебе, а не..."

(+) ====
Довольно интересная статья, совершенно недостоверная, но забавная
Нет уж, дудки! — откуда взялось выражение
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/etymology/net-uj-dudki--otkuda-vzialos-vyrajenie-5e279f40cddb7117247720ee

В ней с некоторым настойчивым, я бы даже сказал "чрезмерным", упорством доказывается происхождение от библейских и даже древнегреческих сюжетов, но все возводится в конечном счете к обману. А ведь значение "фиг вам" все объясняло бы превосходно - со всей логикой автора.

> Поэтому мне интересно, какое переносное значение у слова дудеть –
> врать или твердить одно и то же?

Оба. И еще, вероятно, третье, о котором я сказал.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.  Я, возможно, не очень ясно сформулировала свой вопрос, поэтому дополню его.

Comment: @Sharon вы, вероятно, просто не поняли моего ответа. Я добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь синонимов (надо полагать, - современного языка) https://sinonim.org/s/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8#f
к слову «дудки» выдает слова и сочетания исключительно со смыслом «отрицание / отказ»: нет; очень нужно; очень надо; еще чего; нету; дожидайся; ни за какие коврижки; никак нет; была охота; благодарю покорно; держи карман; жирно будет.
Может показаться странным, но среди  синонимов к слову «дудки» этот словарь не приводит ни одного, за которым бы стояли значения «обман / враки» или «твердить / бубнить».
Среди https://rbook.me/book/15680385/ пословиц, собранных Далем В.И., нашлась парочка про «дудки»:
-Не ударишь в дудку, не налетит и перепел.
-Время на дудку не идет (не вабится).
В обеих пословицах «дудка» – это охотничий манок на птицу, зверя.
Согласно https://zen.yandex.ru/media/des/iskusstvo-ohoty-duhovye-manki-i-ih-ustroistvo-opyt-syn-oshibok-trudnyh-5fe2415218461f3f84ad37b8 «…манок состоит из тонкой трубочки с верхней прорезью, в которую вставлены две преграды, первая ограничивает проход воздуха в камеру с прорезью, второй регулируется размер самой прорези».
Звук манка (дудки) привлекает дичь имитацией голоса самца /самки, т.е., обманным способом. Так возникает ассоциативная связь «дудки» = «обман / враки».
Для извлечения звука в манок дуют. Так может возникнуть логическая связь между словами «надуть» и «обмануть».
Что бы приманить объект охоты, зов (манком) приходится воспроизводить многократно. Поскольку манок не благозвучный муз. инструмент, его гудки (дудки?) ощущаются монотонными и нудными. Так у слова «дудки» могло возникнуть значение «твердить одно и то же».
Маловероятно, что третье значение слова «дудки» (отрицание / отказ) произошло от первых двух (врать и талдычить). Такое значение скорее могло образоваться как эвфемизм от достаточно оскорбительного словосочетания «дулю тебе», полученного путем «дуля – дуть - дудки».